# image regression in TF2 Keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow, regression, cnn

I am trying to figure out, how I could build a model which takes an input image of varying illuminations and outputs an image which has adjusted illuminations by a given label-image.

I found out that regression might be the right keyword to search for, unfortunately I haven't found anything useful yet (neural style transfer, regression). The closest thing would be this [here](https://github.com/iver56/image-regression).
However, according to this git it will takes the image coordinates to "regress" towards the label pixels.

What I have so far is something like this:

```
input_shape = np.shape(img) # array of(300, 300, 3)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 300x300 with 3 bytes color
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),


    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_img_pixels, activation='relu')
])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
# x are training images, a tensor with 4 dims [batch_size, 300, 300, 3]
# y are training labels a tensor with [batch_size, 300*300*3]
model.fit(x, y, ...) 

result = model.predict([test_img])
result = np.reshape(result[0], input_shape)
```

Due to the lack of my knowledge I would like to know if there is a similar problem out there and how I could solve that.
Thanks in advance.